# Qui qu'a / qui n'a

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour,

J'ai trouvé cette phrase dans *Féerie I* :

> Qui **qu**’a pas été en cellule c’est du chochotte drôle…

Je ne comprends pas très bien l'usage du pronom dans *qui* ***qu**'a*. Est-ce un emploi de la langue parlée ?

Est-il correct ? Ne dirait-on plutôt *qui n'a pas*... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, c'est du français très relâché, cette forme me semble assez rare.

Voilà quelques équivalents, du plus soutenu au plus relâché :

Qui n'a pas...
Celui qui n'a pas...
Celui qui a pas...
Celui qu'a pas...
Çuilà qu'a pas...
Qui qu'a pas...

Comment: Effectivement, ça semble être du français relâché et un peu daté aussi car autant de nos jours on peut entendre "çuilà qu'a pas" ou "çui qu'a pas", autant "Qui qu'a pas", sauf à l'interrogative ("C'est qui qu'a pas (...)?") ne me semble pas/plus utilisé